# open new window with map extent derived at runtime in original window

Tags: javascript, window, arcgis

I asked this question on gis.stackexchange but it was suggested that this is more of a web than an ArcGIS issue...
I am trying to open a new window from an existing window, which will contain a map with an extent derived from the original window. In other words, the user will zoom to an area in the original window, click a button, then a new window(or tab) will open with a map set to the zoomed extent. I am using the ArcGIS Javascript API. I have tried several JS/jquery/html methods to make this work, (window.load, ,$window.ready)..but nothing has worked for me. I continue to get an error in my new page saying that 'map' is undefined, and I can see in Firebug that my function to set the new extent based on the extent of the original page runs before the page is fully loaded. I hope I am explaining this problem clearly. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks,

Comment: Do you have a link where we can see it in action?

Comment: I am assembling a new code set now...unfortunately our workspace was pummeled by Hurricane Sandy, and we have been doubling up in other offices in NYC, and I still have no access to our development servers...I will get some sample code up here as soon as I can...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be running any code that configures the active map inside the onLoad event for the map, so that it runs after the map object itself is loaded....so somewhere in your startup code you need:

`//create the map object
var map = new esri.Map("mapDiv", {options});
//hook the onLoad event
dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", function() {
    //set your extent here
});`

Comment: I'm not sure the answer above addresses my question (or I am not clear)..anyhow, I found that simply using window.opener to get variable values from the parent page into the child page solves most of this problem, as long as the map has a new html id in the new page...I save the extent of the parent page into global variables, and then I can access them in the child page.

Comment: I read your problem as being that your code to set the extent of the child window was running before the map *in* the child window was created. It sounds like you were actually saying the code in the child window couldn't find the map in the parent window in order to get the extent it needed?

Comment: I think your reading of the problem was correct.  Using window.opener to get the extent from the parent page seems to work for me as a workaround.